# -E startup option and SSDs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Has anybody seen evidence of the effect of `-E` when using SSDs?

The effect on 'spinning rust' drives is not disputed - but SSDs aren't really flustered by random I/O. I wonder if the `-E` option might even hurt performance.

On servers with a mix of drives (SSD SAN, PCI SSDs and traditional SAN) SQL Server has to decide on startup whether to use `-E` or not. I have some empirical evidence that the option might be detrimental to performance, but I'd like other people's feedback before I consider taking it off.

My setup uses standard 64K RAID stripes, and the NTFS cluster size is also 64K.

Answer (score 3):

The following articles explore the advantages and disadvantages of the `-E` start-up option:

[Focus on Fast Track : Understanding the –E Startup Parameter](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamesrowlandjones/archive/2010/04/25/focus-on-fast-track-understanding-the-e-startup-parameter.aspx)

Summary:

`-E` changes the [proportional fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187501.aspx) algorithm. Rather than moving on to the next file after a single extent allocation, the movement occurs after 64 extents have been allocated.

These extent allocations do not need to come from a single table. For example, when loading two tables in parallel with `–E` enabled, both tables consume the 64 extents in the single file before moving on to the next file. `-E` does not alter the fact that SQL Server allocates one extent at a time.

The purpose of `–E` is to enable large-I/O read-ahead.  If two tables that share the same files/filegroup are loaded in parallel then the advantage of `–E` is removed. The extents will be fragmented resulting in small-I/O read-ahead.

`-E` was originally put into the code to allow index builds and rebuilds to use 256KB of each file before round-robining, and so get better sequential I/O for large data warehouses. It was originally a 'benchmark special' and had very little testing, it was only documented because it was used during benchmarks (and so had to be documented).

[Microsoft White Paper (pdf)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/antr/ms/ssd.pdf)

*<sub>Community Wiki answer generated from a comment on the question by @Kin</sub>*